# Can't remove vertical padding or margins on Wrap widget

Tags: dart, flutter

This is what I get on the screen.

[image]

I want the red FlatButtons to have no vertical spacing on top, bottom or between them. The only yellow visible should be horizontal space between them.

Here's the code that generates this Widget:

```
Widget _buildSelectedFriendsRow() {
    var widgets = List<Widget>();
    selectedFriends.forEach((friend) {
        widgets.add(
            FlatButton(
                child: Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Text("${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}",
                        ),
                        Icon(
                            Icons.close
                        ),

                    ],
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                onPressed: () {
                    _unselectFriend(friend);
                },
            )
        );
    });

    Widget widget = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                spacing: 10.0,
                runSpacing: 0.0,
                children: widgets,
            ),
        ),
    );

    return widget;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `FlatButton` if you don't need it, try using `InkWell` and `Container` .

Change this:

```
    FlatButton(
                    child: Wrap(
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Text("${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}",
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.close
                            ),

                        ],
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    onPressed: () {
                        _unselectFriend(friend);
                    },
                )
```

To this:

```
    Material(
    color: Colors.red,
     InkWell(
            child: Container(
              child: Wrap(
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Text("${friend.firstName} ${friend.lastName}",
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.close
                            ),

                        ],
                    ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
                _unselectFriend(friend);
            },
          ),  
      ),
```

Comment: I actually don't need the colors. I added the colors so I can see where the edges of the elements are on the screen. I just need something clickable inside a Wrap, and that clickable thing has to have some text and an icon inside. 

I am open to any combination of widgets that can accomplish that.

Comment: then remove the color from my code :),  did you try my answer? :D

Comment: Just did. It worked. Tweaked it a bit and got exactly what I was looking for. THANK YOU !!!!!